# deploying a SpringMvcPortlet in a gradle project

Tags: spring-mvc, gradle, liferay-7

im using liferay 7.1 ,and when i want to deploy a SpringMvcPortlet i got this error :

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':wars:mySpringMvcPortlet:compileClasspath'.

> Could not find javax.validation:validation-api:.
> Required by:
> project :wars:SpringMvcPortletFormation
> Could not find org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:.
> Required by:
> project :wars:SpringMvcPortletFormationPossible solution:

- Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Do you have an idea where my error is?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have a dependency issue here, you have to manage all your dependency for the SpringMvcPortletFormationPossible project, and you need to put them properly in the build.gradle file,
So I recommand to add   `mavenLocal()` to the `repositories { }`  to be able to search all the local dependencies from the local repo and find them properly:
Example:

```
  buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.gradle.plugins", version: "3.13.8"
        }
    
        repositories {
           mavenLocal()
            maven {
                url "https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
            }
        }
    }
apply plugin: "com.liferay.plugin"

dependencies { .... // your dependency here // .... } 


repositories {
       mavenLocal()

    maven {
        url "https://repository-cdn.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
    }
}
```